# Castle Project ActiveRecord - can it use stored procedures with SQLServer 2005?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I am new to Castle Project ActiveRecord.
I have starting getting my hands dirty and I just seen that It can generate for you the schema, add data, update data to the schema.

There are advantages of using stored procedures in SQL Server 2005, one of them being they are precompiled.

Is there a way of telling Active Records to use a particular stored procedure when inserting/editing data to the schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord uses NHibernate.  See here for information on how to use stored procedures with it:

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/18/UsingNHibernateWithStoredProcedures.aspx